# SQL Proc if else not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a SQL proc which looks like this:

```
If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '1') 
Begin
// do this 
End

Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '0')
Begin
// do this 
End
```

Until here, it works as it should. However, the next 2 statements do not work, I am wondering why.

```
Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')
If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '1')
Begin
//do this
End

Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')
If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '0')
Begin
//do this
End
```

ShowNoCustomer Par value is 100% sure value 1 by default, but I can change it within the application to 0.

There are no errors, but it just doesnt do the sql I want it to do when ShowNoCustomer is 1.

Comment: By any chance ParValue is null? in KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers

Comment: What means 'do not work'?

Comment: What error was rised?

Comment: ParValue is 1, there are simply no errors. I just dont get anything back when Parvalue is 1 in shownocustomers. I was thinking my Sql statement was wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your logic is flawed, and you haven't used begin/end fully to nest everything as it should be. This should be equivalent, and correct logic:

```
Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')
Begin
    If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '1')
    Begin
        //do this
    End
    Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '0')
    Begin
        //do this
    End
End
```

There's no need for `Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')` to be repeated, and the lack of  begin/ends is confusing you as to the execution path.

Alternatively, this version is even briefer and makes 1 query instead of 2 when the ShowStartEndTimeInd value is 0:

```
Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')
Begin
    --using a variable so we only have to do the query once
    Declare @ShowStartEndTimeVal varchar(5)
    Select @ShowStartEndTimeVal = ParValue From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' 

    If @ShowStartEndTimeVal = '1'
    Begin
        //do this
    End
    Else If @ShowStartEndTimeVal = '0'
    Begin
        //do this
    End
End
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe nesting your sub ifs within a begin/end pair from the else ifs resolves this issue (ensures each statement fires on a "true")

```
Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')
    begin
        If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '1')
            Begin
            //do this
            End
        /*Else*/ If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowStartEndTimeInd' And ParValue = '0')
            Begin
            //do this
            End
    end
```

Comment: I don't think the second `Else If exists (Select 1 From ST_Setting Where Parameter = 'KWI_TR_ShowNoCustomers' And ParValue = '1')` will ever fire here, because of the "else" part. And it's redundant anyway.

Comment: Good spot,
I've removed the redudancy and updated my code above, including a commented out else in case the OP requires the first "event" to exclude the following one